# Strongswan ubuntu client setup?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I have setup strongswan VPN server and tested the connection from windows machine. Its working fine. But **can't connect from Ubuntu desktop client using Strongswan-network-manager**.

Someone please give suggestion how to setup strongswan client on Ubuntu,

Comment: Any one have chance to check this ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the strongswan networkmanager plugin in the 16.04 LTS Version of Ubuntu:

- https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/1429

You need to build and install the latest version of network-manager-strongswan plugin to get a connection.

Comment: Welcome on the ServerFault. It is good that you copied the most important part of your reference into the post. To avoid the link rotting problem, it is a requirement here, that your answer should remain comprehensible even if the remote link would be unreachable.